# Tag rename "htmllayout" to "html-layout"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

As we can see there are tags called [css-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations), [html-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table) etc ...the dash separating two words.

It would be nice to have [html-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-layout) which deals with laying out the html element issue on the browser based application rather than [htmllayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmllayout) for consitency.

I went through some issues which are tagged as css-* and html-*  ..et.  I have found out the laying out the component is an issue for many asked questions. This allow us to focus more on this issue

Comment: Why do we need a tag for HTML layout? Isn't that pretty much what everyone does with CSS and HTML? I can't think of a reason to narrowly classify questions regarding the `html` element as opposed to any other element.

Comment: Not sure how to formulate it. I see the layout issue weather from android or from java swing or from html is a very nasty and complex problem. Under the css and html  tag, we can see many issues related to the layout. We have browser war with many browser vendors which makes the layout more complex . In the Java Swing it was one vendor and have many issues and very complex with different layout managers etc...  On the other hand why there are css and html specific tags like css-animations and html-table etc.. while there is none for html-layout.

Comment: There are CSS and HTML-specific tags because there are specific problems dealing with CSS animations (e.g., `@keyframe`s) and HTML `table`s (e.g., fixed `thead`s). But issues with HTML layouts are all, at their root, based on problems with a specific technology (CSS grids, flexbox, HTML frames for the unlucky, etc.). Those specific technologies should be in the tags, not something as broad as "layout" or "html-layout", in my opinion.

Comment: there is nothing in the CSS or HTML specification called *layout*. All the CSS-* /HTML-* tags are related to components or features where you can find at least a documentation of a part of the specification talking about. Why not *html-design* or *html-structure* in this case?

Answer (score 2):

This is now mostly done. [htmllayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmllayout) and [html-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-layout) were both merged into the "master" tag, [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout), and synonym mappings were created.

Of the questions previously tagged with [htmllayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmllayout) were these two, which appear to be about a framework/library with an "HTMLLayout" object:

- [how to change time column in HTML layout of Log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642961/how-to-change-time-column-in-html-layout-of-log4j2)
- [view logback logs of my web application online (HTMLLayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201149/view-logback-logs-of-my-web-application-online-htmllayout)

I'm not sure if these need to be retagged. I have to defer this to a subject-matter expert, or at least someone who has some knowledge of web-based frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

We already have [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout) which already covers this issue.

> The layout tag is for questions about the placement, alignment and justification of objects with respect to a containing element. For questions pertaining to CSS, use the 'css' tag instead

I'd propose deleting/burniating [htmllayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmllayout) (there are only 6 questions) and creating [html-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-layout) and synonomise *that* with [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout)

Comment: The layout tag seems to apply to HTML layouts or any other type of layouts (e.g. it mentions "android layouts" in its about page). It's way too vague, IMO.

Comment: Unholy codethulu the layout tag is a dumpsterfire; but with >20k questions clean/burning it into html-layout, android-layout, etc would be nearly impossible short of convincing an SE employee to do the heavy lifting via a few tag driven database update queries.

Comment: I agree there should be android-layout and html-layout  The layout be specific to html or android.  Massive problem around html layout in relation to css but there is a lack of tagging them also. I guess html-layout will make things better for issue related to browser

Comment: *I guess html-layout will make things better for issue related to browser* --> we have browser specific tags for this, *html-layout* is simply useless. Use html+ browser tag